# converting .bib to .csv and keeping all the fields

Tags: csv, bibtex

i have several .bib files that includes fields like "Doc-Delivery-Number" & "Web-of-Science-Categories" and I would like to cast it to .csv file - including all the weird fields.

im using **jabref** and  at the moment  when i'm exporting to csv, it adds all sorts of fields that i dont have like "Editor" , and custom fields like "Custom3" that i don't know how to get to.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69481/converting-bib-database-into-csv try zotero or use a pythonscript ...